# Complex nested dictionary from a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list called rest which contains many dictionaries in a list which is in the format

```
rest = [{'a':'b','c':'d','e':'f'}, {'a':'g','c':'h','e':'i}, {'a':'j','c':'k','e':'l'}]
```

Can I get an output as below where I have new as a key inside a dictionary for all the key-value pair except the first key-value pair

```
output = [{'a':'b','new':{'c':'d','e':'f'}},{'a':'g','new':{'c':'h','e':'i'}},{'a':'j','new':{'c':'k','e':'l'}}]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: How do you define first? Dictionaries used to be unordered until recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the syntax `first, *remainder` to extract the relevant parts and then create a new dict from them:

```
def convert(d):
    first, *remainder = d.items()
    return dict([first, ('new', dict(remainder))])
```

Then to convert each of the dicts:

```
output = [convert(d) for d in rest]
```

Note that this syntax was introduced in [Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#new-syntax) and dictionaries are unordered before [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation) (i.e. the first item is not determined).